# Powerpoint Visited Hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a table of hyperlinks in PowerPoint, and I would like a visited hyperlink to change color (or disappear altogether preferably) after I click it.

It's a Jeopardy board and I would like to click "Category for $100", for example, then go to the answer slide, and when I return to the main board, the $100 value I clicked would either be a different colour or removed altogether.

I have tried using the animation on text, but it only removes the links in a pre-determined order on click of the slide.  I want to remove them as I click them (as the audience chooses their question).

Thanks for any help you can provide!

*I'm using Powerpoint for MAC, but not sure if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, Powerpoint uses a different color for followed hyperlinks (changes color after the link is selected). My guess is that the color theme that you're using has the same color the hyperlink and followed hyperlink. No experience with Macs but here's some info about how this works on Windows.

With powerpoint on Windows here's how you edit the colors used for hyperlinks.

Select the Design tab and click on Colors.  From here you can select a template that uses different colors for the hyperlink and followed hyperlink.  If none exist, create your own template. Note that you cannot edit the built-in themes. To edit custom themes, right-click on the theme and select Edit...

[image: create custom theme]
[image: change hyperlink colors]

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered a very stupid work-around, but a work around nonetheless.  Delete your values (links included) in the table you created. Add a text box inside one of the table cells instead (just make one and copy). Put in the numerical value you want. Now add the link for the slide to the text in the text box. Voila it changes color when you click on it.